# C# Xamarin Firestore Bad gRPC response, how to fix?

Tags: c#, xamarin, google-cloud-firestore, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I try to receive data from the Firestore Database to my Xamarin Forms Android project,
but everytime I try to receive the data, I get this exception:

```
Grpc.Core.RpcException: 'Status(StatusCode="Internal", Detail="Bad gRPC response. Response protocol downgraded to HTTP/1.1.")'
```

This is the code that gets the exception:

```
        async void DBRead(FirestoreDb db)
        {
            CollectionReference usersRef = db.Collection("Users");
            QuerySnapshot snapshot = await usersRef.GetSnapshotAsync();
        }
```

The same code works in a normal console application, but not in Xamarin Forms.

Any help would be much appreciated!

I tried to get the data in a normal console application, and it worked, but not in Xamarin with the android emulator.

Comment: Please make sure your server has HTTP/2 enabled. if you aren't using TLS then a port can't use HTTP/1.1 and HTTP/2. It can only use HTTP/2. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/troubleshoot?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: @AlexandarMay-MSFT what is meant by "server" ? I am trying to connect to the Firestore Database with a client based on Xamarin Android.

Comment: The means the Firestore Database you connect to.

Comment: @AlexandarMay-MSFT I am not sure if that (or how) is possible, and it does work in a console project but when I use the Xamarin Android emulator, it does not.

Comment: Please refer to the issue with the same error:[Xamarin Android fails to send GRPC/Http2 requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60360430/why-does-xamarin-android-fails-to-send-grpc-http2-requests)